# Convert XML into XPath Format

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a simple XML below:

```
<tns:Naglowek>
    <tns:KodFormularza kodSystemowy="JPK_V7M (1)" wersjaSchemy="1-0">JPK_VAT</tns:KodFormularza>
    <tns:WariantFormularza>1</tns:WariantFormularza>
    <tns:DataWytworzeniaJPK>2001-12-31T12:00:00</tns:DataWytworzeniaJPK>
    <tns:NazwaSystemu>token</tns:NazwaSystemu>
    <tns:CelZlozenia poz="P_7">1</tns:CelZlozenia>
    <tns:KodUrzedu>0202</tns:KodUrzedu>
    <tns:Rok>2001</tns:Rok>
    <tns:Miesiac>0</tns:Miesiac>
    <tns:KodFormularzaDekl kodPodatku="VAT" kodSystemowy="VAT-7 (21)" rodzajZobowiazania="Z" wersjaSchemy="1-0E">VAT-7</tns:KodFormularzaDekl>
    <tns:WariantFormularzaDekl>21</tns:WariantFormularzaDekl>
  </tns:Naglowek>
```

I would like to display the tags similar to how `XPath` looks like, such as:

```
Naglowek
Naglowek/KodFormularza
Naglowek/WariantFormularza
Naglowek/DataWytworzeniaJPK
Naglowek/NazwaSystemu
Naglowek/CelZlozenia
Naglowek/KodUrzedu
Naglowek/Rok
Naglowek/Miesiac
Naglowek/KodFormularzaDekl
Naglowek/WariantFormularzaDekl
```

I've tried online converters, but they're only showing me below:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

How can I convert XMLs into XPath Format?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, try this one. See explanations in the comments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- set the output method -->    
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <!-- delete all text nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <!-- match the root node -->
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match all non-root nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="*[ancestor::*]">
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text><!-- a linebreak -->
        <!-- select all ancestor node local names, separated by a slash-->
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::*/local-name()" separator="/"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('/', local-name())"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action [here](http://xsltransform.net/3MXS28M).